# How to close AlertDialog.Builder without clicking any button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ListDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.str_choose, new YesListener());
ListDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.str_cancel, new NoListener());
dialog.show();
```

Above code is mine.
I can dismiss dialog by click button.
But if I want to dismiss it without click any button.
How can I do it?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder seems has no cancel() and dismiss() function.

Comment: But what is the id of dialog?

Comment: You should read [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) too see different ways of creating, showing, removing and dismissing dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a handler to delay the call to `Dialog.dismiss()`. Here's an example.

Define the appropriate instance variables in your `Activity`:

```
// number of milliseconds to wait (2 seconds, in this example).
public static final int DELAYED_RESPONSE = 2000;
// define a handler as a private instance variable in your Activity.
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Use the following code to post a new `Runnable` that will dismiss your dialog after `DELAYED_REPONSE` milliseconds:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dismissDialog();
    }
}, DELAYED_RESPONSE);
```

Note that this code assumes that your `Activity` implements a method `dismissDialog()` that will dismiss your dialog accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it would be to create a `Handler` on your UI threads looper and then post a delayed `Message` or `Runnable` that executes `Dialog.dismiss()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set `setCancelable(true)` by doing this you can press BACK button of the device.
Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setCancelable(true).show();
```

Comment: If it met a certain requirement? it gets dismissed?